# How to avoid google sheet cell with formula or with dynamic data to be re-writed?

Tags: google-sheets

If the google sheet is used multiple users, how to make sure nobody re-write those cells with formula or with dynamic data?

Answer (score 0):

you can `Protect range`

[image]

or protect even whole sheet

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### If you want to protect a cell do it through the UI

As per the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656) you can prevent a range to be changed by following the steps provided. By now there's no such feature to protect a cell through sheet functions.

### As a workaround use Google Apps Script

By programmatically protect a range you can handle dynamic data, this involves GAS though. As an example if you want to prohibit anyone other than yourself from editing cells:

```
function protectRangeProgramatically() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1");
  
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
  protection.addEditor(me);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
}
```

### References

- [Protect, hide, and edit sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656)
- [Class Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#setdomainediteditable)